# CSS - Display text at descent instead of baseline?

Tags: html, css, typography

Is there a proper way to display text at the descent height of a line instead of its baseline?

Please reference the following pages:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baseline_(typography)

and

http://jsfiddle.net/YPPnU/

The goal is to have the bottom of my text (as pictured in the fiddle) flush with the bottom of the H1 block without using images.

I realize that it is flush if I use descending characters(p, q, etc)  however, I will never be using them for the scope of this project.  I need characters without descenders to be flush with the bottom of the h1 block.

I've tried various adjustments with positioning and negative margins, but this presents two problems
1) the height of the h1 gets messed up.
2) the amount of the negative bottom could vary depending on the font-face used.
Is there a "proper" way to do this?

***edit***
Please see comments for additional updates....

Best working technique is here:
http://jsfiddle.net/YPPnU/23/

**But I would prefer not to "guestimate" the line-height**

Additionally, I realized another option would be to use a webfont where the bottom of all characters was placed at the descent instead of the baseline, but I can't seem to find one on google.  Does anyone know if such a thing exists?

Comment: How about adding line-height: 0.65em; to h1

Comment: The text is flush with the bottom if you have a character with a descender (such as "j") in the `<h1>`.

Comment: @Eric: `.69em` is even better.

Comment: Not on my browser it isn't. Leaves a small gap at the bottom (after zooming stupidly). Admittedly, I was trying to align the A with `.67em`, and forgot about the slightly lower other letters

Comment: Dont see what is the problem here. With relative positioning, how does it change the height - http://jsfiddle.net/LJatP/

Comment: Thanks for the tips about the line-height.  I've been working around with a variation of your ideas and have come up with this so far:
http://jsfiddle.net/YPPnU/23/

I'm probably going to use a webfont with @font-face anyway....so this really lets me control the line-height I would need.  I would still prefer a computed and exact total so there is no room for error as there would be with fudging hundredths of an em, but I think this will be close enough....of course, I am still willing to entertain other ideas!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What about `vertical-align: bottom` with `line-height: 65%`?

http://jsfiddle.net/y53uK/

Comment: This is cleaner than my edited solution where I had inserted a padding-top of .29em to preserve the space above the letters.  I may end up using this, but as stated, I would prefer to not guess at the line-height as it will vary with different fonts.

Comment: Yeah, you're absolutely right. I'm not quite sure why it is the way it is but those two properties seemed to help. But you're right, that `line-height` value was some arbitrary value that seemed to fit that particular font and size.

Comment: It should be noted that the line-height required will vary from font to font. There's nothing magical about 65%, it's just the value needed to match the baseline in this example.

Comment: Great suggestion. Works like a charm!